# How can I inset multiple data from a foreign key?

Tags: sql, insert, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert a data from a table together with the data from the foreign key. For example, after the customer signing up. The data (that includes the id, name, contact) will be inserted in the Customers Table then the Customer ID will also be inserted in the QRCode Table since Customer ID is a foreign key. Now my problem is, how to include the "name" and the "contac"t in the QRCode table? Can anyone suggest what should I use?

Comment: Please provide the create table statements (including PKs, FKs etc) and some sample data for both tables

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

In general, you don't.  You just include the `CustomerId` in the two tables.  When the time comes and you need the name or other information, you use a *`join`*:

```
select qr.*, c.*    -- or whatever columns you want
from qr join
     customers c
     on qr.customerid = c.customerid;
```

In general, you want to avoid storing multiple copies of the same information in different tables -- it bloats the database and makes it hard to maintain.

Let me note that the above is a general rule.  There are some cases where you might want to copy data in this situation (say, slowly changing dimensions), but as a general rule, data attributes should be stored in only one table, with `join`s used to combine data from different tables.